# How do I insert tagged html text into an rich text editor(CKeditor)?

Tags: html, tags, ckeditor, richtext

I have a bunch of data that is tagged text in my database.  An example of tagged text would be:

```html
when you buy any <strong><u>TWO</u></strong> Frozen Pillsbury Dinner Rolls \r\n
```

I want to display this on my webpage within a rich text editor such as CKeditor.  I set the value on the CKEditor `<textarea>` to be this tagged text and it shows it with the html tags and the \r and \n at the end.

How can I display this text without the tags and in the correct format?  In this example, having it display with the word 'TWO' bold and underlined.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer - I'm glad it was helpful. I would appreciate it if you upvoted it too though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in the CKeditor there's a button that says Source on the top right corner of the toolbar. Click that, paste your tagged HTML text and then hit Source again. Tada!